# Best practices in monitoring the Android SMS database asynchronously

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android app in which I'm currently using AsyncTask to monitor the android SMS `database/provider` ("content://sms").
This `AsyncTask` is run whenever the main activity is started.

Now, I want to be able to do it asynchronously, i.e., update my database whenever an SMS is sent or received.

I'm currently using an `IntentService` to do so, using `AlarmManager` to set a repeating run every 2 mins.

I've also experimented with a 'STICKY' service that uses a `ContentObserver` to run a thread using `handler.post()` whenever an SMS is sent or received.

My doubts are:

1) Which method is more efficient? the one implementing the 'STICKY' service or the IntentService method?

2) If I use handler.post(), imagine the following scenario:
     An SMS is received and the thread is run.
     When this thread is running, if another SMS is received, will a new thread be created and running simultaneously with the old one?

3) Is there any other way than what I've tried so far?

Thanks.

Comment: Option 3: Use a BroadcastReceiver and listen for android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED and android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT?

Comment: Still available on API 16?